# Array Question in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

As I know, I can define an array in PHP.

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
```

But how can I

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   insert each of $row member to $input ?
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to achieve your goal?

Comment: PHP has a very good documentation. You can find everything you need to know here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @Michiel Pater, Yeah. But I must wait for 10 minutes to mark as my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can do that easily this way**

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   $input[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in one time if im correct:

```
$input = array_merge($input, $query->result());
```

if you want to change something in the result from you query you have to do it as the way other answers do.

EDIT:

```
if(gettype($query->result()) == "array")
{
    $input = array_merge($input, $query->result());
}
else
{
    // if it is a object its changed to array
    $input = array_merge($input, (array)$query->result());
}
```

Comment: This assumes that `$query->result()` is an array, which is not clear.

Comment: Check for it.. this is the fastest way to do it. How more results you get, how slower your foreach will be.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
  $input[] = $row;
}
```